# Building JOGL gives gcc error during c.build.nativewindow.awt: jawt.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized

Tags: gcc, build, ant, jogl

I built Ant and I am using it to build JOGL. I reverted to java 1.8 for this build. I installed MinGW32 and I can use gcc. I built gluegen with ant and it worked like a charm. Doing the same thing in jogl on a clean build gives the following log (abbreviated):

```
    c.configure:

c.build.nativewindow.windowlib.x11:

c.build.nativewindow.windowlib.windows:
     [echo] Output lib name = nativewindow_win32
     [echo] c.compiler.use-jawt false
     [echo] nativewindow_win32.useLibJAWT ${nativewindow_win32.useLibJAWT}
     [echo] Compiling nativewindow_win32
     [echo] java.lib.dir.platform: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre/../jre/bin
       [cc] 4 total files to be compiled.
       [cc] cc1.exe: warning: command line option '-fno-rtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
       [cc] C:\Users\micha\git\opengl\jogl\src\nativewindow\native\NativewindowCommon.c: In function 'NativewindowCommon_CurrentTimeMillis':
       [cc] C:\Users\micha\git\opengl\jogl\src\nativewindow\native\NativewindowCommon.c:155:5: warning: 'gettimeofday' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       [cc]      gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
       [cc]      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
       [cc] In file included from C:\Users\micha\git\opengl\jogl\src\nativewindow\native\NativewindowCommon.c:4:0:
       [cc] c:\mingw\include\sys\time.h:106:53: note: declared here
       [cc]  int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW __POSIX_2008_DEPRECATED gettimeofday
       [cc]                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
       [cc] cc1.exe: warning: command line option '-fno-rtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
       [cc] cc1.exe: warning: command line option '-fno-rtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
       [cc] cc1.exe: warning: command line option '-fno-rtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
       [cc] Starting link

rename.dylib:

rename.mingw.dll:
     [move] Moving 1 file to C:\Users\micha\git\opengl\jogl\build\nativewindow\obj

gluegen.properties.load.user:

gluegen.cpptasks.initialize:
     [echo] os.name=Windows 10
     [echo] os.version=10.0
     [echo] os.arch=amd64
     [echo] nativejartag.prefix = jogamp/nativetag
     [echo] c.compiler.debug=false
     [echo] c.compiler.use-debug=${c.compiler.use-debug}
     [echo] c.compiler.optimise=none

gluegen.cpptasks.striplibs:
     [echo] Strip symbols from libs in ../build/nativewindow/obj

c.build.nativewindow.windowlib.macosx:

c.build.nativewindow.windowlib:

c.build.nativewindow.awt:
     [echo] Output lib name = nativewindow_awt
     [echo] c.compiler.use-jawt true
     [echo] nativewindow_awt.useLibJAWT true
     [echo] Compiling nativewindow_awt
     [echo] java.lib.dir.platform: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre/../jre/bin
       [cc] 6 total files to be compiled.
       [cc] cc1.exe: warning: command line option '-fno-rtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
       [cc] cc1.exe: warning: command line option '-fno-rtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
       [cc] cc1.exe: warning: command line option '-fno-rtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
       [cc] cc1.exe: warning: command line option '-fno-rtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
       [cc] cc1.exe: warning: command line option '-fno-rtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
       [cc] cc1.exe: warning: command line option '-fno-rtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
       [cc] Starting link
       [cc] ..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\bin/jawt.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized
       [cc] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\micha\git\opengl\jogl\make\build.xml:71: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\micha\git\opengl\jogl\make\build-nativewindow.xml:761: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\micha\git\opengl\jogl\make\build-nativewindow.xml:701: gcc failed with return code 1

Total time: 12 seconds
```

I am running Windows 10, Ant 1.10.5. I am aware that the "File format not recognized" error means

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out immediately after posting this. I was using MinGW**32**, when I should have been using the 64 bit alternative. Upon switching to MinGW64, the build succeeded.